# Conditional expectation of a functional of an Itô's semimartingale under its equivalent martingale measure

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Consider a probability filtered space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb F, \mathbb P)$, where $\mathbb F = (\mathcal F_t)_{0\leq t\leq T}$ satisfying the habitual conditions and is generated by $1 d $- Brownian Motion (with $\mathcal F_T = \mathcal F$).

Also, consider a process $X = (X_t)_{t \in [0,T]}$ given by
 $$X_t= X_0 + \int_0^t  \mu_s ~ds +\int_0^t \sigma_s ~dW_s \quad , t  \geq 0$$

where $t \in [0,T] \mapsto \mu_t$ and $t \in [0,T] \mapsto \sigma_t \geq 0$ are **deterministic and continuous functions**.

Suppose that there is a measure $\mathbb Q \sim \mathbb P$ and a $\mathbb Q$-brownian motion  $W^{\mathbb Q}$ such that 
$$X_t= X_0+\int_0^t \sigma_s ~dW_s^{\mathbb Q}\quad , t  \leq T$$

I want to evaluate the function $p$ defined as by

$$ p(t,x) := \mathbb E^{\mathbb Q} \left [ (X_T-\kappa X_1)^+ | X_t=x \right] \quad \text{for} \ (t,x) \in [0,1]\times(0,\infty)$$

where $\kappa >0$ and $T>1$.

For this, I was claimed to show the  following relation (that I failed to demonstrate)

$$ p(t,x) = x F(1,\kappa, \int_1^T \sigma_s ^2 ds) \quad \text{if} \ t\in [0,1]$$

where, for $y, K, \gamma^2 >0$
$$F(y,K,\gamma^2) = \mathbb E \left [ (ye^Y -K)^+ \right] \quad \text{with} \ Y \sim \mathcal N(-\gamma^2/2, \gamma^2) \  \text{under} \ \mathbb P$$

I have tried to explore the fact that $ ( X_T-\kappa X_1)^+ =X_1(X_T/ X_1-\kappa )^+$. It can possibly help those that have some financial mathematical background, to know that the motivation behind this is problem is the pricing of a Forward start option.

I would appreciate any advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect some typos crept in (for example $p(t,x)$ should depend on $t$ but the formula you suggest does not). Could you check your formulas?

Comment: @did: There is typo, it's $F(1, \kappa, \int _1 ^T \sigma_s ^2 ds )$ and not $F(1, \kappa, \int _0 ^T\sigma_s ^2 ds)$.

Comment: @Did: But I still don't understand why it doesn't depends on $t$ over $[0,1]$. I  had not remarked it before you said, thank you.

Comment: I suspect there are still some serious problems in this question... What is your source?

Comment: @Did:An old exam. It's not impossible.

Comment: @Did: I've tried to explore the fact that $ (X_T-\kappa X_1)^+ = X_1(X_T/X_1-\kappa )^+$ but I was not well succeded. The inspiration behind this problem is the pricing of a Forward start option. Maybe it says somthing for you. I don't know if you are familiar with this kind financial framework.

Comment: As long as you are asking to prove that $p(t,x)$ is something that does not depend on $t$, the question seems to be "not a real question".

Comment: @Did : Considering the quality of the texts produced by the "author" of the original question, I have strong doubts about the existence of a mistake on it. Nonetheless, nobody is free of making mistakes. As soon as we don't find an evident reason to justifie an error, I'd admit it's correct and try to sove it admiting that the formula expresses implicitly that it doesn't depend on $t$ over $[0,1]$. If you see a rough mistake in this hypoteses, please let me then know your justificative. Thank you in advance.

Comment: See answer. $ $

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $\kappa=x=0$, $\sigma_t=1$ and $\mu_t=0$ for every $t\geqslant0$, then $\mathbb Q=\mathbb P$, $(X_t)_{t\geqslant0}$ is a Brownian motion, and $p(t,0)=\mathbb E[(X_T)^+\mid X_t=0]=\mathbb E[(X_{T-t})^+\mid X_0=0]=\sqrt{T-t}\cdot\mathbb E[Z^+]$ where $Z$ is standard normal.

In the same setting, $p(t,0)=\sqrt{T-1+(1-\kappa)^2(1-t)}\cdot\mathbb E[Z^+]$ for every $\kappa$.

Comment: It's a perfect simple reasoning over a particular case in spite of the fact you can not suppose $\kappa =0$ since it's strictly positive.

Comment: I am sure you can adapt the example to cover this case.

Comment: I'm not so sure, but I'll try it.

Comment: You missed the condition $x \in (0,+\infty)$

Comment: Actually I did not and, as a matter of fact, this is an aspect of the proposed formula for $p(t,x)$ which makes it rather absurd since $\lim\limits_{x\to0}xF(\cdots)=0$ although $\lim\limits_{x\to0}p(t,x)\ne0$.

Comment: You are totally right! Coud you try with $\mu_t = \tilde{\mu}(X_t) X_t$, $\sigma_t = \tilde{\sigma}(X_t) X_t$ where $\tilde{\sigma}>0$ and  $\tilde{\sigma},\tilde{\mu}$  deterministic, please ? I guess it can be the error.

Answer (score -1):

Note that
\begin{align} p(t,x) &:= \mathbb E^{\mathbb Q} \left [ X_1 (X_T/ X_1-\kappa)^+ | X_t=x \right]  \\&= \mathbb E^{\mathbb Q} \left [ X_1 \mathbb E^{\mathbb Q} \left [(X_T/ X_1-\kappa)^+ | \mathcal F_1\right] | X_t=x \right]  \\&= x \mathbb E^{\mathbb Q} \left [ (X_T/X_1-\kappa )^+ | X_t=x \right]    \end{align}

for all $t<1$ and  $x \in (0, +\infty)$, since $X$  is a $\mathbb Q$ -martingale. Now, if we include the aditional condition on $\sigma$ that $\sigma_t := \tilde\sigma(X_t) ~X_t$, we can conclude that
\begin{align} p(t,x) &= x F(1,\kappa, \int_1^T \tilde\sigma(X_s)^2 ds),  \end{align}

where $F$ is defined as in the question BUT under $\mathbb Q$ and not under $\mathbb P$ as  it says.

Comment: Why do you replace twice $X_1$ by $X_t=x$ in the identity defining $p(t,x)$?

Comment: @Did: $X$  is a $\mathbb Q$ -martingale

Comment: This is correct. And?

Comment: See adit to a detailed reasoning. The term $  X_1 \mathbb E^{\mathbb Q} \left [(X_T/ X_1-\kappa)^+ | \mathcal F_1\right]$, in 2nd line is a product of martingales, 3rd line is justified by the markov propertie of $X$.

Comment: Right, $X$ is a martingale, and? Why the 4th line? Of course, $E[X_1\mid X_t=x]=x$ but here you have $E[X_1Y\mid X_t=x]$ with either $Y=(X_T/X_1-\kappa)^+$ or $Y=E[(X_T/X_1-\kappa)^+\mid X_1]$. How you manipulate this is a mystery to me.

Comment: @Did: Please, see edit. I'm supposing that $X_1Y$ (with $ Y = \mathbb E [(X_T/X_1 - \kappa)^+| \mathcal F_1]$) is a product of independent martingales. Second line is justified by tower propertie.

Comment: Independent? Well well well...

Comment: That's what I must still show or not ... What do you think about? Any idea?

Comment: Seriously? That the example in my answer shows that you are trying to prove a result which does not hold (note that in my post, $\mathbb P=\mathbb Q$).

Comment: Note that you doesn't give a counterexample for my question since $\kappa$ is strictly positive by assumption. That's the main subject of the question and with $\kappa =0$ it does'nt have any interest.

Comment: You already said that and I already told you that `I am sure you can adapt the example to cover this case`. If you refuse to check that there is really no difference between $\kappa=0$ and $\kappa\ne0$ (for example, by a straightforward continuity argument...), this is up to you (but do not expect me to debunk your future tries as I did with the previous ones). Sorry.

Comment: I'm really sorry if I explained myself poorely. I'd like to understand what is wrong with this reasonement. So, I must prove that the martingales in the product are not independent. I am here to learn by discussing ideas and mostly by asking my douts (that's the case here) with is the objective of this forum d'ailleurs.